# android activity without graphic

Tags: android

From the BroadcastReceiver I want to call a activity without graphic. Without graphic because it will speak some words.

```
Intent iSpeechIntent = new Intent(context, TTS.class);                          
iSpeechIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(iSpeechIntent);
```

but activity cycle is not finished correctly. `onDestroy()` method is never executed. Why?

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

And is OK if i am using activity without graphic XML just for speak some text with TTSEngine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). `onDestroy()` is **NOT** called when your activity is dismissed. And dismissing it (i.e. by starting another activity) does **NOT** equal destroying activity (however you may enforce destroy of activity, by calling `finish()` - and then your `onDestroy()` method will be invoked). You may want to move your code to `onPause()` and `onResume()` respectively or maybe you shall use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) instead, if you dot require any UI for the task.

Comment: thank you for explain. I will try with IntentService. i am also using ispeech TTS which as parameter for initialization needs Activity.

Answer (score 1):

I propose to use Android Service for such kind of tasks http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html .